# Mathematical expectation question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Following are the results obtained for two independent random variable x and y. $E(x)=4,E(y)=6,v(x)=5$ and $V(y)=4$, so find the value of

$1)\ $ $E(2x-y)^2$

$2)\ $ $E(7-2x-5y)$

That's the way I am trying :

$$V(x)=E(x^2)-E(x)^2 $$

$$5=E(x^2)-16$$
$$E(x^2)=21$$
In the same way 
$$E(y^2)=40$$
$$E(xy)=6\times 4=24$$

\begin{align}E(2x-y)^2 &=4E(x^2)-4E(xy)+E(y^2) \\
              &=4(21)-4(24)+40\\
              &=84-96+40\\
             &=28
\end{align}
But actual answer is $60$ which doesn't match.

Comment: As you may have noticed, most of your posts was closed down. Do not just paste the question statement as shown in a typical homework format on the site. Include your thoughts and attempts. It is good to include your working in the original post as compared to telling us what you have found without showing us the working. Take it as an exercise to  edit the post to include the working so that one of us can tell where you make the mistake if there is any. Also, textbooks do make mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part,\begin{align}
E[(2X-Y)^2] &= Var((2X-Y)) + [E(2X-Y)]^2 \\
&= 4Var(X)+Var(Y)+(2E(X)-E(Y))^2
\end{align}

Comment: I did this way answer comes 28. Is it correct or not please tell me.Because my answer is not matching to the book answer .

Comment: your answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks. But lot of people writing in comments that my questions are not asked in prescribed format and I am not showing my workings. Actually I am new to this site. Can you guide me about asking questions.

Comment: what most people are looking for is what you have attempted so far. Here is a [link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/306553) on how to ask a question on the site.  Most of the time just try your best to include your working in [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553). It is alright if your attempt is wrong. Welcome to MSE.

Comment: Thanks you very much you are really kind and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For independent random variables, $E[XY]=E[X]\cdot E[Y]$.

Comment: I tried this but my answer comes 28 which doesn't match the actual answer is it me wrong or actual answer?